# How to set text for password field via uiautomator

Tags: android, android-testing, android-uiautomator

I can't set text for password field via uiautomator:

```
UiObject eaPassword = uiDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().textContains("Password"));
assertTrue(eaPassword.waitForExists(35_000));
eaPassword.click(); // optional
eaPassword.setText("1234"); // return true
```

It is able to find the object itself.

If I execute `eaPassword.getText();` it returns `"Password"`.

Comment: why don't you use Espresso?

Comment: @WenChao I will be happy, if I could. the architecture of application is too complicated to test it via simple Intents. Ui Automator is better for such task.

Comment: What class object is that `View`?

Answer (score 4):

If you run eaPassword.click() , screen would be change(keyboard pop up),
so you cannot find eaPassword(Uiobject) again

setText()  this function has two behavior
1. Long press EditView
2. Input text

```
UiObject eaPassword = uiDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().textContains("Password"));
assertTrue(eaPassword.waitForExists(35_000));
eaPassword.setText("1234");
```

or try other method

```
UiObject eaPassword = uiDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().textContains("Password"));
assertTrue(eaPassword.waitForExists(35_000));
eaPassword.click();
setStrings("test");

 public void setStrings(String text) {
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            char c = text.charAt(i);
            if (c >= 48 && c <= 57) // 0~9
                uiDevice.pressKeyCode(c - 41);
            else if (c >= 65 && c <= 90) // A~Z
                uiDevice.pressKeyCode(c - 36, 1);
            else if (c >= 97 && c < 122) // a~z
                uiDevice.pressKeyCode(c - 68);
            else if (c == 42) // *
                uiDevice.pressKeyCode(KEYCODE_STAR);
            else if (c == 35) // #
                uiDevice.pressKeyCode(KEYCODE_POUND);
            else if (c == 46) // .
                uiDevice.pressKeyCode(KEYCODE_PERIOD);
            else if (c == 47) // /
                uiDevice.pressKeyCode(KEYCODE_SLASH);
            else if (c == 58)  // :
                uiDevice.pressKeyCode(KEYCODE_SEMICOLON);
        }
}
```

It would be one by one to input word (not use setText())